# How can I add a UITableView into a UIView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I've a UIView - `containerView`.

I have a table view controller - `aTableViewController`.

I'm trying to add the table view into the table view controller using:

```
[containerView addSubview:aTableViewController.tableView];
```

But there isn't anything in the containerView. Hmm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks correct. Ensure that all of `containerView`, `aTableViewController` and the `tableView` are initialized properly. Try printing them out just before this line and ensure they are not `nil`

Comment: thanks, you are right. i should have checked if they are `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that when you are initialising `aTableViewController` with `– initWithFrame:style:` the `frame` property is set correctly.